# Checking empty fields in HTML5 contact form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I wrote an HTML5 contact form which is submitted using ajax. I would like to display an message when one of the fields are empty. In my code the if statement shows the message,but it disappears to fast. How can I trigger the paragraph to make it stay until form is submitted again

Thank you anyone in advanced

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
        var name = document.getElementById("name");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone");
        var message = document.getElementById("textarea");


        if(name.value=="" || email.value=="" || phone.value=="" || message.value=="")
        {
            var warning = document.getElementById("warningMessage");
            warning.innerHTML = "Error: Please complete required fields in order to submit";
            warning.style.border = "1px solid #FF3030";
            warning.style.background = "#FF6E6E";
            document.getElementById("name").focus();
            document.getElementById("myForm").reset();       
        }  
        else
        {
           $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"sendEmail.php",
                data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
                success:function(){
                    alert('Form was submitted properly');
                    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
                }
            });
            //return false;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML5 form:

```
<form method="post" name="form"  id="myForm">
    <label >Request Service</label> </br>
    <label >Note:<span> * </span>indicates all require field</label> </br>
    <label>Name: <span>*</span></label></br>
    <input type="text" required="required" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name" id="name"></br>
    <label>Email: <span>*</span></label></br>
    <input type="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="Please enter your email" id="email"></br>
    <label>Phone:</label></br>
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number" id="phone"></br>
    <label>Message:</label></br>
    <textarea name="comments" maxlength="500" cols="25" rows="6" placeholder="Enter message" id="textarea"></textarea></br>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submmit">
</form>
<p id="warningMessage"></p>
```

Comment: put `return false` after `else{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message disappears quickly because the `submit` event is not cancelled beforehand.

You could catch this and prevent the page jump by doing:

```javascript
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     /// the rest of your code.
```

When the event is prevented, the default action will not be taken by the browser, in this case, submitting the actual form through a plain old HTTP request, as you're doing just that with your ajax call.

Have a look at this [code example](http://jsfiddle.net/rrazvtLz/) to see it in action.

Comment: It totally works, can you explain the behavior of e.preventDefault(); please??

Comment: Well, when you bind that anonymous function to the `submit` event on `#myForm`, the code will run, but it won't prevent other `submit` handlers, like the default one for the browser, to run. The problem with your code is not that the message disappears, but that the page reloads.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If this answer solved your question, it'd be great if you could mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I will Sir, I can not do it now. I have to wait two more minutes for that

Answer (score 0):

It's dissapearing "too fast" because you are executing the code to show and reset the element without any delay between the statements. You also may need an e.preventDefault() on your click event. You already are using jQuery so you've got some simpler approaches:

First, just apply the proper css to the div itself, with display: none. There's no need to set this more than once, or with javascript.

```
    style="display: none; border: 1px solid #FF3030; background: #FF6E6E"
```

Then, replace your alter your click event:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from submitting by default action

    if ($("#name").val() == "" || $("#email").val() == "" || $("#phone").val() == "" || $("#textarea").val() == "") {

    $("#warningMessage").html("Error: Please complete required fields in order to submit");
    $("#warningMessage").slideDown().delay(3000).slideUp();
    // If you don't like the slide transitions, use fades by replacing the line above with the following line:
    // $("#warningMessage").fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();

    ... // rest of js code
```

This code will show the element, wait 3 seconds, and then hide it again.